# How can i fix this with ListBox issue?

Tags: vb.net, timer, listbox

this is my code:

```
Private Sub StartToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As     System.EventArgs) Handles StartToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Video1.Start()
    Video1.Interval = 4000
    ToolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "Browsing"
End Sub

Private Sub Video1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Video1.Tick
    ToolStripStatusLabel4.Text += 1
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = rnd.Next(0, ListBox1.Items.Count - 1)
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
End Sub
```

---

Problem is lets say the timer interval is set to 4 secods (4000). i want my application to navigate to each item in my ListBox in order: website1, website 2, website3, ect. But instead its doing this: website 5, website2, website 8, website 1. Its navigating to randome website.

Comment: one more thing, how can it be doen so when the last item has been selected that the timer is then set to stop, as im getting an error saying:ArgumentOutOfRange Exception, InvalidArgument=Value of '5' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's random appears to be because you are calling the random number generator and selecting that item from the list box:

```
rnd.Next(0, ListBox1.Items.Count - 1)
```

Instead you should allocate a variable which stores which index you are currently on. Increment this each time the timer ticks.

```
Private currentIndex As Integer = 0

Private Sub Video1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles Video1.Tick
    ToolStripStatusLabel4.Text += 1
    currentIndex += 1
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = currentIndex
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
End Sub
```